# Integrate jasperserver 5.2 with jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, jasperserver

I need to integrate jasper server with jboss application server. Can anyone guide me the steps.

Thank you.

Comment: `I need to integrate` - What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed steps in the JasperServer install guide, chapter 5
http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-install-guide.pdf